# Select where with timestamp values null not work

Tags: sqlite, laravel, laravel-5

On laravel 5.3 with SqliteDriver

table cpjobs

```
...
$table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable(false);  // saved data unixtime
$table->timestamp('delayed_at')->nullable(true);  // saved data unixtime
...


| id  | delayed_at | start_at    |
|-----| ---------- | ----------- |
| 2   | null       | 1477912725  |
| 3   | 1478007928 | null        |
| 4   | null       | null        |
```

if run on tinker

```
Cpjob::where('delayed_at', '>', '1478007902')->first();
    => App\Cpjob {#694
         id: "11",
         type: "backup",
         created_at: "1477911786",
         delayed_at: "1478007928",
       }
```

But if run a complex for delayed_at > now and start_at null, return empty result, when must be return row with id 4

```
 Cpjob::where([['delayed_at', '<', '1477912725'],['start_at', null]])->first();
=> null
```

If get SQL generated...

```
>>> Cpjob::where([['delayed_at', '<', '1478007734'],['start_at', null]])->toSql();
=> "select * from "cpjobs" where ("delayed_at" < ? and "start_at" is null)"
```

I've tried several way for send time, unix timestamp, carbon, but all, produces same  **< ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `whereNull()` for this as:

```
Cpjob::where(fuction($q) {
        $q->where('delayed_at', '<', '1477912725')
          ->orWhereNull('delayed_at');
      })
      ->whereNull('start_at')
      ->first();
```

Comment: Not work. Show null. Values null on column `delayed_at` not work.

Comment: A lot of thanks. Yesterday  see solution, and create my own local scope on Cpjob, Apreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks for tip.

Create my local scope

app/Cpjob.php

```
public function scopeFirstJob($query,$unixTime)
{
   return $query->whereNull('start_at')->where(function ($q) use ($unixTime) {
       $q->where('delayed_at', '<', $unixTime)->orWhereNull('delayed_at');
   })->first();
}
```

Call form my command

```
$job = Cpjob::firstJob($unixtime)
```